# One to One relation mapping using GORM for Golang

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I am trying to understand how GORM works for one to one relational mapping with MySQL. I have 2 structs like so:

```
type User struct {
    Id              uint   `gorm:"AUTO_INCREMENT"`
    FirstName       string `gorm:"column:first_name"`
    LastName        string `gorm:"column:last_name"`
    EncryptedUserId string `gorm:"size:255"`
    Email           string `gorm:"not null;unique"`
    Password        string `gorm:"not null;unique"`
    CreatedAt       int64  `gorm:"type(timestamp)"`
}

type UserSession struct {
    Id           uint `gorm:"AUTO_INCREMENT"`
    UserId       User 
    SessionToken string `gorm:"column:session_token"`
    CreatedAt    int64  `gorm:"type(timestamp)"`
}
```

`User` and `UserSession` share one to one relation. But when code above is run, the column `UserId` for `UserSession` table is not created. Even after specifying the foreign key constraint `gorm:"ForeignKey:Id"`
the result is same. Why isn't the above code working? Is anything missing in the struct definition?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment your questions so I would ask it here:
Do you migrate your schema in any way like:

```
db.AutoMigrate(&User{}, &UserSession{})
```

?
If you do, you should get some detailed errors in log, which might be useful for you.

Comment: Yes I have added the `db.AutoMigrate(&User{}, &UserSession{})` , error shown in log is `(sql: converting Exec argument #0's type: unsupported type models.User, a struct)`

Answer (score 0):

The way I have managed to get something similar to work is this.

```
type UserSession struct {
    Id           uint `gorm:"AUTO_INCREMENT"`
    UserId       uint
    User         User
    SessionToken string `gorm:"column:session_token"`
    CreatedAt    int64  `gorm:"type(timestamp)"`
}
```